# Problema a la hora de ejecutar mi proyecto en android con GameMaker

Tags: java, android, game-maker

Cuando intento ejecutar mi proyecto de `GameMake`r en `android` me sale este error:

> Saving project to: C:\Users\Anra\Documents\GameMakerStudio2\BattleRoyal\BattleRoyal.yyp
>   "cmd"  /c subst Z: "C:\Users\Anra\AppData\Roaming\GameMakerStudio2\Cache\GMS2CACHE"
>
> elapsed time 00:00:00.0526236s for command "cmd" /c subst Z: "C:\Users\Anra\AppData\Roaming\GameMakerStudio2\Cache\GMS2CACHE" started at 02/23/2018 19:44:12
>   "C:\ProgramData/GameMakerStudio2/Cache/runtimes\runtime-2.1.3.189/bin/Igor.exe"  -options="C:\Users\Anra\AppData\Local\GameMakerStudio2\GMS2TEMP\build.bff"  -- Android Package
>
> Loaded Macros from C:\Users\Anra\AppData\Roaming\GameMakerStudio2\Cache\GMS2CACHE\BattleRoya_EDE7CFF_28E253F9\macros.json
>   Options: C:\ProgramData/GameMakerStudio2/Cache/runtimes\runtime-2.1.3.189\bin\platform_setting_defaults.json
>   Options: C:\Users\Anra\AppData\Roaming/GameMakerStudio2\anrape96_1507844\local_settings.json
>   Options: C:\Users\Anra\AppData\Roaming\GameMakerStudio2\Cache\GMS2CACHE\BattleRoya_EDE7CFF_28E253F9\targetoptions.json
>   C:\ProgramData/GameMakerStudio2/Cache/runtimes\runtime-2.1.3.189/bin/GMAssetCompiler.exe  /c /zpex /mv=1 /iv=0 /rv=0 /bv=0 /j=8 /gn="BattleRoyal" /td="C:\Users\Anra\AppData\Local\GameMakerStudio2\GMS2TEMP" /cd="Z:\BattleRoya_EDE7CFF_28E253F9" /zpuf="C:\Users\Anra\AppData\Roaming/GameMakerStudio2\anrape96_1507844" /m=llvm-android /tgt=8 /llvmSource="C:\ProgramData/GameMakerStudio2/Cache/runtimes\runtime-2.1.3.189/yyc/"  /nodnd /cfg=default /fU="Z:\BattleRoya_EDE7CFF_28E253F9\functionsUsed.txt" /o="C:\Users\Anra\AppData\Local\GameMakerStudio2\GMS2TEMP\BattleRoyal_718B2F3_YYC" /optionsini="C:\Users\Anra\AppData\Local\GameMakerStudio2\GMS2TEMP\BattleRoyal_718B2F3_YYC\options.ini"  /cvm /baseproject="C:\ProgramData/GameMakerStudio2/Cache/runtimes\runtime-2.1.3.189\BaseProject\BaseProject.yyp" "C:\Users\Anra\Documents\GameMakerStudio2\BattleRoyal\BattleRoyal.yyp" /preprocess="Z:\BattleRoya_EDE7CFF_28E253F9"
>   Permission Error : Unable to obtain permission to execute
>
> C:\ProgramData/GameMakerStudio2/Cache/runtimes\runtime-2.1.3.189/bin/GMAssetCompiler.exe exited with non-zero status (-1)
>   elapsed time 00:00:00.7643946s for command "C:\ProgramData/GameMakerStudio2/Cache/runtimes\runtime-2.1.3.189/bin/Igor.exe" -options="C:\Users\Anra\AppData\Local\GameMakerStudio2\GMS2TEMP\build.bff"  -- Android Package started at 02/23/2018 19:44:12
>   "cmd"  /c subst Z: /d
>
> elapsed time 00:00:00.0360401s for command "cmd" /c subst Z: /d started at 02/23/2018 19:44:13
>   FAILED: Package Program Complete

---

> **Permission Error** : Unable to obtain permission to execute

Tengo bien el `skd`, `ndk` y el `jdk` y no se como solucionar esto, he intentado un montón de cosas como ejecutarlo como administrador, pero nada me funciona nada, alguien que use gamemaker para sus juegos en android y sepa como solucionar este error.

Comment: Prueba a meter el sdk, el ndk, y el jdk en la misma carpeta. Antes no me salia ,así que lo metí en la misma carpeta y me salió andando, prueba lo.

Answer (score 1):

Este error no depende de tu configuración y esta relacionado a que estas usando una versión "Cracked" o "Pirata".

Para evitar el problema:

> Permission Error : Unable to obtain permission to execute

Obten una licencia para que puedas obtener el certificado:

https://www.yoyogames.com/get

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes una licencia válida, desinstala la versión 2.1.3 e instala la última versión desde yoyogames, inicia sesión y se corregirá el error.

Solución permisos:

> Error de permiso: no se puede obtener permiso para ejecutar

- Esto sucede cuando el programa se instaló sin permisos de administrador
- La solución es sencilla, en el acceso directo le das

  `click derecho y ejecutar/abrir como administrador`
- Si quieres que quede como administrador por defecto, entonces haz:

  `click derecho > propiedades > compatibilidad > cambiar la configuracion para todos los usuarios > ejecutar este programa como administrador`